# Calendar Overlay: Retain colors when click on views

Tags: calendar

I created views based on a category field and then created calendar overlays based on those views.

The view I created were all calendar views as when I first created standard view it didn't show up when creating a calendar overlay.

The only problem I'm facing is when I click on a view I created showing up in the left quick launch menu where the default calendar isn't going to the view but just the default calendar and the default color

Hope this makes sense: it's not retaining the views and the colors selected when I did the overlays.

Edited here - Images here to see:
This is the default view with color coding which works well:

[image]

Holiday View which I can't see a link to the view and the colors don't retain. But I have used Amal's solution below in this post but that mean I have to do it for every view.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no out of the box way to set that. You best option is to edit the view page and add a snippet web part. Inside the snippet use below style

```
.ms-acal-item {
    background-color: red; /*Change red to the color you mentioned in the overlay*/
}
```

Comment: Hi Amal,thanks for the response but can you please elaborate more? Do i have to set this for each calendar overlay i created and where should i set this.

Comment: @naijacoder you need to click the calendar from left quick launch. This will take you to the calendar view where you are losing the color. Edit the page and do as I suggested

Comment: Thanks Amal will give that ago.

But let me elaborate again
My issues is when i click on the view or select a view its doesnt retain the link to the view on the quick launch despite that the link to the view in the browser is correct and the colors dont show up but the view shows the right items

Comment: Amal that worked like a charm but since the colors are different I would have to edit the page for all the views.
Please see my original post I have edited it with some images.Thanks

Comment: @naijacoder there is no other option other than editing the page and adding the CSS. You can put the page in edit mode to do that.

Comment: Thanks Amal.Please see my edited question in the original post.I do understand i need to use CSS.But what i'm saying is when i click on a view e.g holiday i created it takes to the view but doesn't retain the view as selected on the left

Comment: @naijacoder when you click on any link from left, you will get redirected to the calendar (which don't have the overlays defined). You should read more on how overlay works.